# Bash regular expression for CRON

Tags: regex, bash, cron

Does anyone have any recommendations for the best method to write a regular expression for CRON?

Allow me to explain a little better. I have a config file with individual variables corresponding to the fields in CRON. I need to verify that each field is valid. ie 0-59 for seconds, 0-31 for months etc. I'm using sed to update CRON and if the configuration file has syntax errors (accidental extra characters, letters, anything that CRON doesnt like) the results are disastrous (CRON file is clobbered)

I would need to verify all possible numbers and wildcards and throw an error on anything else. I dont know if im just getting tired or what, but I cant seem to get started logically on this one.

I'm open to any suggestions, not just coding. How to prevent CRON from getting clobbered, maybe editing everything in one string (in config file) for CRON instead of individual variables

Thx for any help

Here is an example of the config. Very simple.

```
# SUMMARY REPORT FREQUENCY ( * Wildcards acceptable )
MIN="30"
HOUR="*"
DAY="12"
MON="*"
WEEK="*"
```

*** UPDATE ***

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS which ships with Bash 4.2.25

and here is the code that is doing the updating.

```
function REPORT.CHECK {
  sleep 1s
  if [ "`crontab -l | grep report.sh`" \> " " ]; then
    CTMP="$(set -f; crontab -l | grep report.sh)"
    if [ "$CTMP" = "$MIN $HOUR $DAY $MON $WEEK cd $DIR && ./report.sh" ]; then
      if [ "$DISABLE" = "false" ]; then
        RETURN="true"
      fi
    else
      if [ "$DISABLE" = "false" ]; then
        CTMPESC=$(sed 's/[\*\.&]/\\&/g' <<<"$CTMP")
        DIRESC=$(sed 's/[\*\.&]/\\&/g' <<<"$DIR")
        crontab -l | sed "s%$CTMPESC%/$MIN /$HOUR /$DAY /$MON /$WEEK cd $DIRESC \&\& \./report\.sh" | crontab -
        RETURN="update"
      fi
    fi
    if [ "$DISABLE" = "true" ]; then
      crontab -l | grep -F -v report.sh | crontab -
      RETURN="disable"
    fi
  else
    if [ "$DISABLE" = "true" ]; then
      RETURN="exit"
    else
      (crontab -l ; echo "$MIN $HOUR $DAY $MON $WEEK cd $DIR && ./report.sh") | crontab -
      RETURN="default"
    fi
  fi
}
```

This snip of code actually does quite a bit. It adds the entry to CRON if it doesn't exist. It also kills the script (well returns exit) if this part (the reporting portion) is disabled in the config, it also updates CRON if it sees that what is in CRON is different than whats in the config and finally if the config is identical to whats in CRON, it just ignores and moves on. Those features are not in order. Hopefully that adds enough detail lol.

Comment: what OS are you using that your crontab is getting clobbered because of bad entries? And how are you editing/updating crontab? My experience with crontab is that a bad entry, added using the `crontab -e` option, will cause the edit to abort, and the file reverts to its previous version. Please don't respond in comments, but update your question with these important details. Good luck.

Comment: +1 for updating your question with useful details!. Wow, thats quite a process. Why not pass in the crontab entry you want to validate to a function named like `entryValid(?)` that checks each `$1, $2, $3, ...` for proper values with a case statement and return `true` or `false` ? 2 things. where does $DIR get defined (maybe it doesn't matter)? 2. Why use back-ticks cmd sub where you clearly know about `$(..cmd..)` substitution? You clearly have the skill to solve this on your own, search here for `[bash] case regexp` (or regular expression and other variations). Good luck.

Comment: Please see my comments above.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sticking with the regex-based approach, this set of regexes (regeces?) should get you started. It doesn't support using names for days of the week or months, nor "frequency" notation like `*/5` to substitute for `every five minutes`. But try this (assuming you have opened your config file into an file id `$configfile`:

```
min=$(grep -P 'MIN="([0-5]?[0-9]|\*)"' $configfile | grep -oP '([0-5]?[0-9]|\*)')
hour=$(grep -P 'HOUR=\"([1-2]?[0-9]|\*)"' $configfile | grep -oP "([1-2]?[0-9]|\*)")
day=$(grep -P 'DAY=\"([1-3]?[0-9]|\*)"' $configfile | grep -oP "([1-3]?[0-9]|\*)")
mon=$(grep -P 'MON=\"(1?[0-9]|\*)"' $configfile | grep -oP "(1?[0-9]|\*)")
week=$(grep -P 'WEEK=\"([0-7]|\*)"' $configfile | grep -oP "([0-7]|\*)")
```

After you've collected these values, you can easily check to see if they're in the correct range -- for example, it's possible for the `HOUR` regex to match `29`, which obviously isn't a real hour. But now that the value is saved, you can do:

```
if [ "$hour" -gt 23 ]; then
  #throw an error, exit the test, whatever
fi
```

Just make sure to quote the variables when you test them! For example, `"$hour"`, not `$hour`. If you have an `*` in a variable and don't quote it, the shell will expand it inline to all the filenames in your current directory.

Comment: Please see my comments above.